# Swiper Slider : How to make transitions to slides in CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, swiper.js

Could you explain me how to make transitions to Swiper.js slides elements ?

I have a slider with slides that each contains an image and a title.

I would like , when a slide is leaving, fadeOut the title/image of my slide, and when the next slide is arriving, make a fadeIn to its title/image.

Make a blackout between slides is also nice.

I have searched something like "onSlideChange" but I don't know how to use it.

This is a website that contain that kind of functionnality in the homepage :

https://www.operadeparis.fr/

Is it difficult to add/remove CSS to slides depending on their state ? (leaving of arriving)

Thank you

Comment: Your Q is too general. In general on enter you could use GSAP of CSS animation (onSlideChange or by CSS selector active and so on).

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your answer :)